# .Net Core API Cross Site Scripting on HttpContext.Request.Form

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, xss

I am having a **.Net Core API** where in i am trying to read the parameter using `HttpContext.Request.Form["TestInput"]`. This particular line is detected as Cross Site Scripting (Reflected) issue by one of the tool. what is the issue and how can we remediate it?

Code :-

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class TestController 
    {
    
    public IActionResult TestAction()
            {
    var str=Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Request.Form["TestInput"]); // this line is detected as Cross Site Scripting issue
    
    // bla bla bla
    return OK();
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: The problem is not on this line, but where you use `str` later. It needs to be encoded according to the context where it's used.

Comment: You can try to use code `string input = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Request.Form["TestInput"]);`

Comment: Convert.ToString(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(HttpContext.Request.Form["TestInput"])); i did this but still the issue exists.

Comment: I want to ask you how this issue appeared?

Comment: There is also what follow-up operations have been performed on the string after you have obtained it.

Comment: @Yinqiu i am using it for some comparison i.e if(str =="xyz")

Comment: What tool are you using? Is your str being referenced in a certain view?

Comment: `var str = Convert.ToString( HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Request.Form["testInput"]));`Is it invalid? Please note that it is `HtmlEncode` and not `HtmlDecode`

Comment: @Yinqiu its an inhouse tool. let me try HtmlEncode as well.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any progress.

Comment: Hi @Md Yunus,Did this solve your problem?

Comment: @Yinqiu yes your suggestion has solved the problem

Comment: @Yinqiu similar issue i am getting on below line of code also 
`
public void testMethod()
{
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/xyz");
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{

//bla bla bla
}
}
`

Comment: var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code:

```
 var str= Convert.ToString( HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Request.Form["TestInput"]));
```